# Tips on how to diagnose a view controller losing reference to parent view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, lldb

I have a class `someViewController` that has a gesture recognizer on one of it's views, and double-tapping triggers the handler for that gesture, which then creates and throws up a UINavigationController, which wraps an iRpImageViewerViewController.

iRpImageViewerViewController is the lone content controller inside that UINavigationController.  I have an NSLog statement that shows the following result at a given point.

```
<iRpImageViewerViewController: 0x84689690>'s parentViewController is <UINavigationController: 0x7ca31800>
```

Then at some point later, I do the double-tap gesture, triggering that code again, and my NSLog statement logs this message.

```
<iRpImageViewerViewController: 0x84689690>'s parentViewController is (null)
```

How on Earth would a UINavigationControllers content controller lose it's connection to it's containing UINavigationController.  I'm not doing anything mysterious or weird, trying to reference or use the content controller, maintaining it's lifetime manually.

Also in the log, which I'm not putting there, is this disturbing tidbit...

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x7e98ee00> on <iRpImageViewerViewController: 0x84689690> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Somehow, somewhere, iRpImageViewerViewController is losing it's reference to it's parentViewController, and its presentingViewController... both are nil.

Is there an LLDB technique to determine where exactly this is happening?

The following 2 variables are used in the code that follows

```
@implementation someViewController
{
    UINavigationController *imageEditorNavController;
    iRpImageEditorViewController *imageEditorVC;
}
```

Then further down in that class, my presentation code is here, triggered when the user double taps on a view in `iRpImageViewerViewController`

```
-(void)handleDoubleTapRecognizer:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
    {
        NSLog(@"Double Tapped, so opening editor");
        IGCellPath *pathForCurrentCell = [self pathForCurrentCell];
        iRpImageAndMedia *imageAndMediaItem = [thePropertyImageSet objectAtIndex:pathForCurrentCell.columnIndex];
        imageEditorVC = [[iRpImageEditorViewController alloc] initWithImageAndMediaItem:imageAndMediaItem];

        imageEditorVC.navigationItem.title = @"Photo Details Editor";
        imageEditorVC.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

        imageEditorNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:imageEditorVC];
        imageEditorNavController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        imageEditorNavController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(imageEditorDone)];
        imageEditorNavController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(imageEditorCancelled)];
        imageEditorNavController.preferredContentSize = imageEditorVC.view.frame.size;

        NSLog(@"%@'s parentViewController is %@",self, self.parentViewController);

        [self presentViewController:imageEditorNavController animated:YES completion:^(void){ }];

    }
```

and

```
-(void)imageEditorDone
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }


-(void)imageEditorCancelled
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: How are you presenting the "A" view controller in the second case?  I note that the object reference is the same - Have you previously dismissed this instance of View Controller A?  Are you trying to present the same instance again?

Comment: I edited my question to include the relevant code (I believe).

Comment: I wish I could help more, but the terms in the question are very confused (the same confusion in the code might be leading to the problem... we've got view controllers A, and B and "someViewController", and a reference to "the image viewer" and an instance var pointing to another type of vc some of these being contained in a navigation controller.... yikes).

Comment: One debug tip is to remember that contained vcs will get a call to willMove and didMoveToParentViewController.  Remember also that parent of in a navigation controller context is a navigationController, and that a presented view controller can get at the vc that presented it with presentingViewController.

Comment: Your question is missing some really important details. Mainly, the code that shows "A" the second time where its `parentViewController` has become `nil`.

Comment: Also really impressive that 4/14 views of this not-particularly distinguished question saw fit to up-vote it.

Comment: @danh  Well, it looks like that was a fluke, and it's quickly making it's way back down, and should be into the negatives by morning, so I wouldn't be too concerned.   When you create a navigation controller and call the initWithRootViewController and pass your content view, doesn't that maintain the hierarchy automagically, and do that work of didMoveToParentViewController?  If not, where would you make that call?

Comment: willMoveToParent is not offered as a fix, but rather for diagnosis.  Any view controller may implement (not call) it.  In the implementation, call super, and NSLog. self and the new parent.  Hopefully that will help you uncover the problem.

Comment: @danh  Ahhh, very clever.  I'll try that.